# Giving Class to an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I just want to know how can I add a class to a container or any other element using js

let's say I want to add a class to a `<div>` when `scrollY>50` how can I do this?

Edit:-

I want to add a class to an element when `scrollY>50` and remove the added class when `scrollY=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `element.classList.add()` property for adding class to an element

```html
<div id='mydiv'>
```

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#mydiv')
element.classList.add('addedClass')
```

Now will add class if scrollY = 50 using `document.onscroll` eventListener & `window.scrollY` for getting scroll value

```js
document.onscroll = () => {
  const element = document.querySelector('#mydiv')
  if (window.scrollY == 50) {
    element.classList.add('addMyClass')
  } else {
    element.classList.remove('addMyClass') // remove class if doesnt match the condition
  }
}
```

The [querySelector()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) method returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document.

The [classList](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp#:%7E:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,()%20and%20remove()%20methods.) property returns the class name(s) of an element, as a DOMTokenList object. This property is useful to add, remove and toggle CSS classes on an element. The classList property is read-only, however, you can modify it by using the add() and remove() methods.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: what are `querySelector` and `element.classList.add` can you give more details plz

Comment: how can I make it run only when scrollY reaches a specific unit like I want it to run only when the `scrolly=50`  how can I do that

Comment: @KrishnaNoutiyal updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant adding a class subject to `if (window.scrollY = 50) {}`, then in such a solution:

## 1 This is vanilla js method:

```
if (window.scrollY = 50) {
   document.querySelector('.class_one').classList.add('class_active');
}
```

## 2 This is jquery method:

```
if (window.scrollY = 50) {
   $('.class_one').addClass('class_active');
}
```

Comment: can you give me details about your first method I don't know much about `querySelector` and `classList.add` what are they

Comment: querySelector() is a method that allows you to declare any selector, and in any order. There are methods like getElementById() is only an identifier, getElementsByClassName() is just a class, .getElementsByTagName() is just a tag name. In querySelector() you can specify both a class, an identifier and a tag - querySelector (".сlass #id span").

Comment: There is a method like `querySelectorAll()`. You can read more here - https://coursesweb.net/javascript/queryselector-queryselectorall#:~:text=The%20difference%20between%20querySelector(),that%20match%20the%20'selectors'.

Comment: and what about `classList.add` what is that

Comment: The `classList` property contains a pseudo-array of CSS classes of an element, and also allows you to add and remove classes of an element, check for a certain class among the classes of an element. `add` is a method for adding a class. There are also methods - `remove`, `toggle`.

Comment: this is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
document.querySelector("[scrollY=50]").classList.add("myClass")
```

Comment: can you give me some detail about what you have done here | I don't know very much about js I am a beginner I know that what `document` is but don't know other things what you have used here like `querySelector` and `classList.add`